# Installing npm packages in non-interactive mode

Tags: node.js, highcharts, npm

I am trying to [install highcharts server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) in my Docker image. But the npm install command asks several questions to the user when installing. I need it to go ahead with default values(Which I can provide in the npm install command). How to achieve this?

In this case the questions are:

```
Agree to the license terms? y/n:  (no) y
Select your Highcharts version (e.g. 4.2.2)::  (latest)
Include Maps? (requires Maps license):  (no)
Enable styled mode? (requires Highcharts/Highstock 5 license):  (no)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variables as described in the documentation?  https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md#using-in-automated-deployments

Comment: export ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE=YES does not seem to work

Comment: You must export 3 variables, so: HIGHCHARTS_USE_STYLED=NO, HIGHCHARTS_VERSION=latest and ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE=YES, put values you want.

Comment: It does not work with 'npm install highcharts-export-server -g' but works with 'git clone https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server;
npm install;
npm link'

Comment: did you try with ENV instead export, or passing option -e in run time ?